# Measure of the boundary of Alexandrov space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact $n$-dimensional Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below. Let $\partial X$ denote its boundary in the sense of the theory of Alexandrov spaces.

> Is it true that if $\partial X\ne \emptyset$ then it has finite and positive $(n-1)$-Hausdorff measure? (The case $n=2$ is already interesting to me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be proved by induction on $n$.
Base case $n=1$.
The step follows since gradient exponent is locally Lipschitz and it maps $T_p(\partial X)=\mathrm{Cone}[\Sigma_p(\partial X)]$ to a neighborhood of $p$ in $\partial X$.
It proves that $\partial X$ has finite $(n-1)$-Hausdorff measure.

The differential of gradient exponent at the origin is the identity map.
It follows that a small cube $\square$ around a regular point in $T_p(\partial X)$ is mapped amost isometrically; in particular the opposite faces of $\square$ go to sets on positive distance. By Besicovitch inequality, the image of $\square$ has positive $(n-1)$-Hausdorff measure.

The same proof shows that an $m$-dimensional extremal subset in a compact Alexandrov space has finite positive $m$-dimesnional Hausdoeff measure.

Comment: It seems to me that this argument only shows $dim_H \partial X \le n-1$. How can one prove $H_{n-1}(\partial X)>0$?

Comment: @Totoro, it is fixed now, thank you.

Comment: May I ask what is the definition of a regular point in $T_p(\partial X)$? As $\partial X$ may not be an Alexandrov space, the definition is unclear to me. Anyway, one can use the same method and prove by induction that any $m$-dimensional extremal set contains a "cube" which is the image of $I^m$ such that the opposite faces of the cube have positive distance.

Comment: @Totoro A point $p$ is a regular point of subset S if the tangent space $T_pS$  is Euclidean.

Comment: Why does $\partial X$ contain a regular point?

Comment: @Totoro any extremal subset have a regular point; if needed I will find a reference.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin "Regular points of extremal subsets in Alexandrov spaces" by Fujioka is a reference. Not sure if there are any earlier reference.